# Updating class name in ngClass directive when model changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ng-class

I'm using AngularJS and Bootstrap grid in order to present some information that needs to be updated real-time. However, this should also update the bootstrap column size and offset. I have two nested repeats and I access the data in the grandparent scope (due to child scopes created by repeats):

```
<div class="col-xs-{{$parent.$parent.colWidth}}" ng-repeat="w in $parent.widths track by $index" ng-class="{'col-xs-offset-{{$parent.$parent.colOffset}}':$first}">
```

The problem arises when I update `$scope.colOffset`: the `[value]` in `col-xs-offset-[value]` is not affected. However, if I add elements to `$scope.widths` the newly created elements have the correct value whereas the original elements have the outdated value.

I am using `$watch` to track changes in `$scope.plate.width` (which is the changing value) and updating the depedent variables `$scope.colOffset, $scope.colWidth, $scope.widths`:

```
$scope.$watch('plate.width', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    var newValue = parseInt(newValue);
    $scope.colWidth = Math.floor(Math.min(12 / newValue, 12));
    $scope.colOffset = Math.floor((12 - $scope.colWidth * newValue) / 2);
    $scope.widths = $scope.getNumber(newValue);
});
$scope.getNumber = function(n) {
    var ar = new Array(n);
    return ar;
}
```

Interesting remark here is that `col-xs-[value]` is updated but `col-xs-offset-[value]` is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the AngularJS ngClass documentation (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass):

> When the expression changes, the previously added classes are removed and only then are the new classes added.

You could add `col-xs-offset-[value]` as a default class and append another class, e.g. `col-xs-first` for the first column, if that solves your problem.

Comment: Inspired by your answer, I edited the div in a following way:
`<div class="col-xs-{{$parent.$parent.colWidth}} col-xs-offset-{{$parent.$parent.colOffset * $first}}" ng-repeat="w in $parent.widths track by $index">`

Comment: This behaviour might result from changing key values not triggering the the "expression change".